# how to find number of digits in factorial of 42?

Tags: java

factorial of 42 is going beyond the final limit of long data type in java. that's why I can't find digits.

42!

Answer (score 1):

The factorial of 42 is of **51 digits** while the max limit of **long** datatype in Java is **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** i.e only 20 digits. But don't worry, Java has a ***Big Integer*** class to store large numbers such as **100!**. But it's a bit slower than primitive data types such as *int*, *long* etc because it stores integers in the form of arrays. There are many ways to implement the Big Integer class but here's the most used way. This code calculates the factorial of 42 and prints the same-

```
    // Java program to find large factorials using BigInteger
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Factorial
{
// Returns Factorial of N
static BigInteger factorial(int N)
{
BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1"); // Or BigInteger.ONE

// Multiply f with 2, 3, ...N
for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

return fact;
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
int N = 42;
System.out.println(factorial(N));
}
}
```

#### Output:

> 1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000

#### Explanation

We have to import the ***Big Integer*** class, which is stored in ***java.math*** package. I have named my file **Factorial.java**, so my class name is Factorial.
In this method, I've created a function, if you want the **code without function**, just comment below. Now in this syntax-
`BigInteger f = new BigInteger("1");`

I've assigned *fact* as Big integer which is equal to 1. In the ***for*** loop,
*i* value is set to 2 s 1*1=1.

```
fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

The above syntax is for the multiplication of Big integers. This multiplies the **Biginteger** *fact* by *i*.

Have a look at this **GeeksforGeeks** article- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the number of digits, I would recommend taking a more mathematical approach. There are ways to compute this number without actually computing the factorial itself. This would not require so big a variable and would be a lot faster.

You could think it this way:

Digits(n!) = floor(log10(n!)) + 1 = floor(log10(n * (n - 1) * ... * 1)) + 1 =floor(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}log10(i)) + 1

A picture of this expression: [expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tmI1.gif)

This would still require iteration, but it deals with much smaller numbers.

If you still want O(1) complexity for this task, you can go with a pretty good approximation I've just tried.

Digits(n!) ~ floor(\int_{1}^{x}log10(x) dx) + 1 = floor(\frac{-x + x*ln(x) + 1}{ln(10)}) + 1

Another image of this formula: [approximate expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ6GR.gif)

Of course, the latter is no absolutely exact since we are now integrating a continuous function. However, it will probably be worth implementing.

Digits(42!) = floor(50.37...) + 1 = 50 + 1 = 51